# Kafka producer retries docs make sense?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

the [current (3.2)](https://kafka.apache.org/32/documentation.html#producerconfigs_retries) producer `retry` documentantion in Kafka is:

> Allowing retries **while** setting enable.idempotence to false and max.in.flight.requests.per.connection **to 1** will potentially **change the ordering** of records because if two batches are sent to a single partition, and the first fails and is retried but the second succeeds, then the records in the second batch may appear first.

Previously, the [documentation for 2.8 was](https://kafka.apache.org/28/documentation.html#producerconfigs_retries):

> Allowing retries **without** setting max.in.flight.requests.per.connection **to 1** will potentially **change the ordering** of records because if two batches are sent to a single partition, and the first fails and is retried but the second succeeds, then the records in the second batch may appear first.

Do the two docs contradict themselves?

From previous experience, **`setting max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1` will ensure ordering even for `enable.idempotence=false`** , which is not what the current documentation states.

---

UPDATE:
I've found that the [default `acks` configurations changed](https://kafka.apache.org/32/documentation.html#upgrade_300_notable) and it might be a clue:

> Notable changes in 3.0.0:
> The producer has stronger delivery guarantees by default: idempotence is enabled and acks is set to all instead of 1. See KIP-679 for details.

However, it is more related to data loss than to ordering.

Comment: kafka documentation is pure junk. there is also this issue that adds more confusion : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5494

Comment: I have no idea how you can have out of order messages when `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1`. You can only send a single batch at a time, per connection. imo: `3.2` documentation is wrong.